# What is context free grammer of $L = \{w: n_c(w) \ne n_a(w) + n_b(w)\}$

Tags: context-free

I can't find out how to find a *context free grammar* for bellow language, is there any specific way to solve that?

$L = \{w: n_c(w) \ne  n_a(w) + n_b(w)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$. Consider the two cases:

1. $n_c(w) > n_a(w) + n_b(w)$: The idea is to create one more $c$ for each $a$ or $b$ produce in the word:
   \begin{align}
                S_c \rightarrow aS_cS_c | bS_cS_c | cS_c | c
       \end{align}
2. $n_c(w) < n_a(w) + n_b(w)$: In this case, we can produce as many $c$'s as $a$ and $b$ combined + 1.
   \begin{align}
                S_{ab} \rightarrow aS_{ab} | bS_{ab} | cS_{ab}S_{ab}|a|b
       \end{align}

The grammar for the required language would be : $S \rightarrow S_c | S_{ab}$.

Comment: How produce $cca$? I think you should write \begin{align}
             S_c \rightarrow aS_cS_c | bS_cS_c |cS_c| c
    \end{align}

Comment: @nima Thanks, I updated my answer.